# How to parse XML data to JSON? How to deserialize XML to Apex class?

Tags: apex, deserialize, parser

I Have Xml data as Follows

```
String Data_XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding=""?> <book><price>100</price><Items>2</Items> </book>';
```

I wanted to deserialize XML to Apex class or JSON

```
Class Book{
    public Decimal price;
    public Integer Items;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no quick and easy way to transform XML either into JSON or into an Apex Class.

I came up against this in a recent project, and I ended up using the [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) and [Dom.XmlNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm%23apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) classes.

There's likely a way to abstract this pattern, but the basic idea that I used was to have an outer class to start the parsing, and then have a bunch of inner classes to represent the structure of the XML. It's effectively an implementation of a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm

In your provided case, the solution is on the simple side

```
public class BookParser{
    List<Book> books;

    public BookParser(String xmlInput){
        books = new List<Book>();

        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(xmlInput);

        Book tempBook;
        for(Dom.XmlNode node :doc.getRootElement().getChildElements()){
            if(node.getName() == 'Book'){
                tempBook = new Book();
                tempBook.process(node);
                books.add(tempBook);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Book{
        Integer items;
        Decimal price;

        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inNode){
            for(Dom.XmlNode innerNode :inNode.getChildElements()){
                if(innerNode.getName() == 'Items'){
                    items = Integer.valueOf(innerNode.getText());
                } else if(innerNode.getName() ==  'price'){
                    price = Decimal.valueOf(innerNode.getText());
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

In general, each inner class that represents part of the XML data structure implements a `process(Dom.XmlNode)` method. The strengths of this pattern are that it limits the complexity of the `process()` method for each class, it doesn't care what order child nodes appear in, and it can parse the entire structure with a single call (here, it would be `BookParser bp = new BookParser(inputXML);`.

Comment: can we parse  XML directly into apex class like JSON ? Ex: DermaGetCityState d = (DermaGetCityState) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), DermaGetCityState.class);

Comment: @govind123raju No, I'm afraid not. The closest example that you'll see to that is generating Apex classes from a WSDL file, but that seems to be intended for use with services that communicate via SOAP. The only option that I know of is to build your own XML deserializer based on the example that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this library:

- [Apex-XML-Serializer](https://github.com/skolakan/Apex-XML-Serializer)

Define class structure to match your soap response XML

```
public class SoapResponse {    

    public EnvelopeModel Envelope {get;set;}

    public class EnvelopeModel{
        public BodyModel Body{get;set;}
    }

    public class BodyModel{
        public AddDataResponseModel AddDataResponse{get;set;}
    }
    public class AddDataResponseModel{
        Public AddDataResultModel AddDataResult{get;set;}
    }

    public class AddDataResultModel{
        public string RecordId {get;set;}
        public string ErrorDescription {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Then deserialize soap response to apex class

```
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
SoapResponse response = (SoapResponse) serializer.deserialize(xmlString, SoapResponse.class);
```