# Apex multi level apex parsing

Tags: apex, xml, xmlparsing

Below is the XML format needs to be parsed with apex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parents>
    <SubParent>
        <SuperParent>
            <Child>
                <SubChild>
                    <SuperChild>
                        <name>Test</name>
                        <code>123</code>
                    </SuperChild>
                </SubChild>
            </Child>
        </SuperParent>
    </SubParent>
    <SubParent>
        <name>Playstation</name>
        <code>PS</code>
    </SubParent>
</Parents>
```

I am pasing this XML in apex as follows:

```
Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
doc.load(xml);

for(Dom.XMLNode child: doc.getRootElement().getChildElements() ){
    if(child.getName() == 'SubParent'){

        for(Dom.XMLNode bchild : child.getChildElements()){
            if(bchild.getName() == 'SuperParent'){

                for(Dom.XMLNode cChlild : bchild.getChildElements()){
                    if(cChlild.getName() == 'Child'){

                        for(Dom.XMLNode eChlild : cChlild.getChildElements()){
                            if(cChlild.getName() == 'SubChild'){

                                for(Dom.XMLNode eChlild : cChlild.getChildElements()){
                                    if(cChlild.getName() == 'SuperChild'){

                                        //Business logic

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want guidance that can I parse these type of XML's without using nested for loops. If yes then in what way?

Comment: You could use the XmlStreamReader instead of the Dom functions: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_reader.htm

Answer (score 3):

My preferred approach to this is to have a class with a set of inner classes that mimic your xml schema. Doing this allows you to break up the parsing work, keeping only a small portion of the overall xml parsing in each class.

This approach doesn't really remove any loops in the end (a nested data structure is pretty much a guarantee that you'll need to use nested loops), but it re-arranges them to be (in my opinion) much easier to digest and maintain.

The following is taken from the question and my answer on [Convert Apex XML response into JSON Format?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198389/convert-apex-xml-response-into-json-format)

A portion of the xml from that question

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
    <status code="ok"/>
    <my-events>
        <event sco-id="1290617895" type="event" icon="event" permission-id="host">
            <name>Adobe connect demo</name>
            <domain-name>meet64541292.adobeconnect.com</domain-name>
            <url-path>/demo/</url-path>
            <date-begin>2017-11-02T19:30:00.000+05:30</date-begin>
            <date-end>2017-11-03T18:45:00.000+05:30</date-end>
            <expired>true</expired>
            <duration>23:15:00.000</duration>
        </event>
        <event sco-id="1290640959" type="event" icon="event" permission-id="view">
            <name>salesforce demo</name>
            <domain-name>meet64541292.adobeconnect.com</domain-name>
            <url-path>/dmeosfsf/</url-path>
            <date-begin>2017-11-02T19:30:00.000+05:30</date-begin>
            <date-end>2017-11-02T19:45:00.000+05:30</date-end>
            <expired>true</expired>
            <duration>00:15:00.000</duration>
        </event>
    </my-events>
</results>
```

The corresponding Apex to parse that.

```java
public class MyXmlParser{
    Results result;

    // In the top-level (outer) class, the constructor takes an XML document as a string
    //   and we start parsing it
    public MyXmlParser(String inputXML){
        Dom.Document xml = new Dom.Document();
        xml.load(inputXML);

        process(xml.getRootElement());
    }

    public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){
        String currentNodeName;

        // This general pattern, looping over child nodes, creating class instances,
        //   and passing XML nodes to them will be repeated multiple times
        for(Dom.XmlNode childNode :inputNode.getChildElements){
            currentNodeName = childNode.getName();
            if(currentNodeName == 'results'){
                result = new Results();

                // Each level only concerns itself with extracting data on its own
                //   level.
                // If you need to call getChildElements() again to get more data, then
                //   in most cases, it's time to pass the baton on to an inner class.
                // This is what keeps the 'parsing' we're doing split up into
                //   manageable chunks
                result.process(childNode);
            }
        }
    }

    // Each XML tag that doesn't contain primitive data types gets its own inner class
    public class Results{
        Status stat;

        // If a tag only contains a collection of child tags, then it makes sense
        //   to make that a collection.
        // You could have another class for this one (which in turn would hold a
        //   collection of events) instead.
        // That's your call.
        List<Event> myEvents;

        // The constructor for each class is pretty basic, we just need to initialize
        //   collections (and not much else)
        public Results(){
            myEvents = new List<Event>();
        }

        // Each inner class gets a "process" method
        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){
            String currentNodeName;

            for(Dom.XmlNode childNode :inputNode.getChildElements()){
                currentNodeName = childNode.getName();
                if(currentNodeName == 'status'){
                    stat = new Status();
                    stat.process(childNode);
                }else if(currentNodeName == 'my-events'){
                    // Dealing with collections of xml nodes requires just a little change
                    //   to our approach.
                    // Instead of passing the 'my-events' node down, we need to extract
                    //   the children of that node, loop over them, and add the results
                    //   to our collection one at a time
                    Event tempEvent;
                    for(Dom.XmlNode grandchildNode :childNode.getChildElements()){
                        tempEvent = new Event();

                        // Note that we only go as far deep into the XML as is absolutely
                        //   necessary.
                        // Once we get to a place where we can pass the processing
                        //   off to another inner class, we do just that.
                        tempEvent.process(grandchildNode);
                        myEvents.add(tempEvent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Status{
        // Tag attributes become class variables
        String code;

        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){
            // Getting attributes from tags is pretty easy
            // The second parameter is the namespace of the tag, which you'll probably
            //   need to play around with yourself (until you can extract the attribute
            //   value)
            code = inputNode.getAttributeValue('code', '');
        }
    }

    public class Event{
        String sco_id;
        String type;
        String icon;
        String permission_id;

        // Tags that contain primitive data types (Strings, Integers, Booleans, Dates,
        //   etc...) also become class variables
        String name;
        String domain_name;
        // ...and so on

        public Event(){
        }

        public void process(Dom.XmlNode inputNode){
            // I'm skipping over extracting the attributes here, since I've already
            //   shown how that's done.
            String currentNodeName;

            for(Dom.XmlNode childNode :inputNode.getChildElements){
            currentNodeName = childNode.getName();
            if(currentNodeName == 'name'){
                // For nodes that contain a value only (no other nodes), we can
                //   extract the value using getText().
                // Strings don't require any special treatment
                name = childNode.getText();
            }else if(currentNodeName == 'date-begin'){
                // Non-string values (like this node, which is a datetime) will
                //   require some special handling
                // Most primitive types have a valueOf() method that allow you to
                //   pass a string in, and get an instance of the appropriate class out
                dateBegin = DateTime.valueOf(childNode.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing what I did there:

- Each level of tag you have in your xml is turned into an inner class
- If a parent tag can contain more than one instance of a child tag, you need to parse into a `List` of that child tag
- Grab attributes and child tags containing nothing but a primitive type as a value (no attributes) at the current level of parsing
- Create a new instance of the appropriate inner class for more complicated tag classes, and pass the job of parsing the xml down the chain

It's worth noting that this approach implements a depth-first traversal of your xml. For apex classes like this, it seems like the limit of function calls on the stack is 1,000. I don't think you can ever get close to that using the `DOM` classes though, as the [documentation on `DOM.Document`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm#apex_classes_xml_dom_document) states that it only allows you to parse xml up to 50 nodes deep.